# php question regarding arrays

Tags: php

I'm a (complete) php noob and need a little help with something.

I'm working on a project whereby a user can select up to 6 categories via a form (I'm using ExpressionEngine). The output is like this:

```
"Cat1","Cat2","Cat3"
```

...and so on. The user can select up to 6 categories on that form.

What I need: even if my result is 3 categories I need to have 6 'cells' - for want of a better word - even if they're empty:

```
"Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","","",""
```

I've tried this:

```
<?php
$str = '(output goes here)';
print_r(explode(',', $str, 6));
?>
```

...but the output give me:

```
Array
(
[0] => Cat1
[1] => Cat2
[2] => Cat3
[3] =>
[4] =>
[5] =>
```

)

How do I get from that to this:

```
"Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","","",""
```

Does this make sense?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 6):

If you have an array that contains 6 items, including 3 empty strings :

```
$arr = array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', '', '', '');
```

You can [`implode`](http://fr.php.net/implode) those into a string, this way :

```
echo '"' . implode('","', $arr) . '"';
```

And you'll get the following output :

```
"cat1","cat2","cat3","","",""
```

Basically, `implode` allows you to put all items of the array into a string, using a separator -- here, the separator is `","` which is what you can between your strings.

And, as implode only put the separator between elements, we have to put an additionnal `"` at the beginning and at the end of the resulting string.

*(Hope I understood what you meant...)*

---

**EDIT after the comment :**

OK, if your `$arr` array doesn't contain six items at the beginning :

```
$arr = array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3');
```

A possibility could be to create an array with empty elements ; like this, for example :

```
$count = count($arr);

// Create an array with empty elements
$padding = array_fill($count, 6-$count, '');
var_dump($padding);
```

And, then, add those to the `$arr` array :

```
// Add the empty elements to $arr
$arr = $arr + $padding;
```

*(You could also use [`array_merge`](http://fr.php.net/array_merge), I suppose)*

And, now, back to our `implode` :

```
echo '"' . implode('","', $arr) . '"';
```

And, this time again, you'll get :

```
"cat1","cat2","cat3","","",""
```

Here's what the `var_dump($padding);` gives, for information :

```
array
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
```

And, yes, you can use the [`+` operator with arrays](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) *(quoting)* :

> The `+` operator appends elements of
> remaining keys from the right handed
> array to the left handed, whereas
> duplicated keys are NOT overwritten.

If your `$arr` could be longer than 6 elements, you could use [`array_slice`][4] to remove the un-wanted elements :

```
$arr = array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', '', '', '', '');
$arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 6);
echo '"' . implode('","', $arr) . '"';
```

Comment: Hi Pascal,

Thanks for your answer. I won't get the empty strings initially.

I might get:

     cat1,cat2,cat3

or

     cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5

In either case I need the output to be no more than 6 items.

Comment: @Martin : I've edited my answer with a couple of additionnal informations and example :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$org = '"Cat1","Cat2","Cat3"';
$arr = explode(',',$org);
$arr = array_merge($arr,array_fill(count($arr),6-count($arr),'""'));
$str = implode(',',$arr);
echo($str); // prints "Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","","",""
```

Works even when `$org` has `6` or less cats:

If `$org = "Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","cat4","cat5"`

`$str` will be `"Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","cat4","cat5",""`

Comment: @codaaddict Many thanks for this. This is the closest to something that works. However, if my initial results are greater than 4 categories I get no results at all.

Comment: With less than 6 it does. But with 6 it does not.

Comment: @Martin: It works fine for 6 too. when there are 6 cats count($arr) will be 6. So 6-6 will be 0, so effectively the original string will be unchanged. Which is the expected result.